# Is there a function/feature in SQL Server to determine if a table has any (recent) activity?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to clean up a database and want to determine which tables are no longer needed so I can drop them.

(**SQL Server 2000**)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes - a query such as this should give you the information you need:

```
SELECT 
        last_user_seek,
        last_user_scan
    FROM
        sys.dm_db_index_usage_stats
    WHERE
        database_id = DB_ID() and object_id = object_id('tablename')
```

**Update for SQL 2000**: No - I believe there's no built in way of getting this information in SQL 2000

Comment: sys.dm_db_index_usage_stats doesn't seem to be available in SQL Server 2000?

Comment: @john2x - No it isn't there in 2000. Please tag your questions with version as it is now 2011!

Comment: Don't think there is a way in 2000 I'm afraid.

Comment: Aww.. :( Just curious, does this tell when a table is used from anywhere? (not just from T-SQL queries and stored procedures, but also from other programs)

Comment: Hi @john2x - not sure what you mean by other programs? Those other programs would have to access via tsql, stored procedures or whatever wouldn't they?

Answer (score 5):

**For SQL Server 2005+**

`sys.dm_db_index_usage_stats` tells you when a plan was last executed that referenced a particular table ([not necessarily that the table itself was accessed in the execution of that plan](http://web.archive.org/web/20180410202012/http://sqlblog.com:80/blogs/paul_white/archive/2011/02/17/Seeking-Without-Indexes.aspx)).

This metadata is not persisted across service restarts however so you'd need to check it after your server has been up for a while.

**For SQL Server 2000**

No this isn't possible I believe. You might be able to infer something about when they were last modified by looking at statistics updated times and `sysindexes.rowmodctr` but I don't think the last time they were selected from was persisted anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

In general, I'd be wary of judgements based on date/time.  Some applications may have functions that are used very infrequently.  For example, a table holding year-end financial reports may get updated only once per year.  Or auditors may appear someday and request financials from prior years, and your company will be in big trouble if it cannot provide that information.

If you have access to the code, then I recommend scanning the queries for accesses to each table.

If you don't, then you might get some info from the index usage stats as recommended by the other answers.  But proceed with caution!

[edit] I see you have SQL Server 2000.  The usage stats is not in this version, and I don't think there is any equivalent.

If the table has datetime columns, you could see when those dates are, but that won't tell you when they were last accessed.

If the table has timestamp columns, you can compare the last timestamp to the latest database timestamp: [`@@dbts`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187366.aspx) and see if the values are very different.  But that's an unreliable guess at best.